# SPC i s not working

Tags: spacemacs, helm

As if there was any need to make it clear, I am quite a noob when it comes to spacemacs. I am running into the following issue: I am trying to follow some tutorials online. In various of them, `SPC i s` is used to insert snippets. Some searches online make me believe that this should be something that comes with helm, which is a layer that I am using. Yet, when I try to type in `SPC i s`, spacemacs just tells me that the command is not defined. I am sorry to ask such a basic question, but I am really out of ideas of what to try.

Comment: Start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). Do see the same problem? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Requires more info. 1. Are you using `master` or `develop`. Which commit hash? 2. More important question, what is the value of `dotspacemacs-distribution` in your `~/.spacemacs`?

Comment: do you use vim typing syle or emacs style? maybe you've disable evil-mode, try M-x evil-mode.